# R dynamic brownian bridge movement model projection error

Tags: r, move

I am helping a collaborator run some code on their machine to calculate utilisation distributions for several animals. We are using the `brownian.bridge.dyn` function in the `move` R package with the following code:

```
dbb.swan<-brownian.bridge.dyn(swan_move, raster=300, ext=0.3, location.error=5, margin=15)
```

It works fine on my machine, but my collaborator gets the following error:

```
Error in .local(object, raster, location.error = location.error, ext = ext,  : 
  The projection of the raster and the Move object are not equal. 
 raster: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
 object: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
```

Both projections in the error message seem identical, so I'm not sure why this is happening. Furthermore, we're not actually specifying a raster object in `brownian.bridge.dyn` (just a cell size), so I assume the grid is being generated from scratch. Does anyone know why this might be happening please?

Comment: And you're both using same `packageVersion('move')`? Error text is [line 119-120](https://gitlab.com/bartk/move/-/blob/master/R/brownianbridgedyn.R), in `move` test is called `equalProj` but actually calls `[terra::same.crs, line. 359](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/master/R/crs.R) move::equalProj was updated two weeks ago as bug fix (anticipating?) upcoming terra release.

Comment: Just to follow up on this -- I have just upgraded R on my own machine and I'm now encountering the exact same error. I'm assuming this is an issue caused by upgrades to packages (perhaps terra?). Any thoughts on why this might be, especially since the projection strings seem identical?

Comment: At this point perhaps take to the `move` GitHub as an issue. Have you had you collaborator send it to you as an RDS to examine side by side? Thinking simply, I'd suspect `k=`, as floating point difference between you two, as all other projects values appear to be integer values, but `=` still means equal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion – I have raised as an issue on GitHub. We haven't shared an RDS, but I'm not sure it would help since we are both having the same problem now (since I have now upgraded to the latest version of `move` also). Thanks for directing me to the lines of code causing the problem. I might define a new function myself with the projection check lines removed to avoid the issue for now.